# 'function' object has no attribute 'META' in Django 1.7?

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 1.7 and python 3.4.

When I go to `/polls/1/` on my browser I get the following error:

```
 AttributeError at /polls/1/
    "function" object has no attribute "META"
    Request Method:     GET
    Request URL:    

    http://localhost:8000/



       `enter code here`Django Version:     1.7


 Exception Type:    AttributeError
   Exception Value:     
   "function" object has no attribute "META"'
   Exception Location:  C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.7-py3.4.egg\django
   \core\context_processors.py in debug, line 40
   Python Executable:   C:\Python34\python.exe
   Python Version:  3.4.1
   Python Path:     

       "['C:\\Users\\Simon\\Desktop\\social network\\mysite',
    'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.7-py3.4.egg',
    'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-5.8-py3.4.egg',
    'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python34.zip',
    'C:\\Python34\\DLLs',
    'C:\\Python34\\lib',
    'C:\\Python34',
    'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages',
    'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
    'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
    'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']"

    Server time:    Fri, 14 Nov 2014 14:00:09 +0100
```

Here is my code:

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from polls.models import Choice, Question


def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)

def detail(request, question_id):
    try:
        question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
    except Question.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    return render(render, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})

def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': question})

def vote(request, question_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
       selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
          return render(request, 'polls/details.html', {
             'question': p,
             'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
         })
    else:
         selected_choice.votes += 1
         selected_choice.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(p.id,)))
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's small typo in your `detail` function, it should be:

```
return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})
```

You typed `render` instead of `request`, and `render` function has no attribute `meta`, provoking the given error.

Comment: Indeed, it helped, sorry for this obvious mistake, I should have read more carefully!

Comment: TY! Folks who learn django in 1 hour here:)